# Why is overflow-x:clip not working on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I wanted to crop my background on mobile phone so the user cant scroll horizontally, it works fine when i use responsive design mode on web browser :

[image]

But when i open it on my mobile phone , it shows like this :

[image]

I know this question have been asked many times, but none of the solutions seems work for me.

this is my code :

```js
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const HeroBackground = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Background src="/images/backgrounds/hero-background.svg" />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default HeroBackground

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: clip !important;
`

const Background = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
  }
`
```

This is the link of my website in case if needed : https://trusting-bohr-a3f5b8.netlify.app/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you are using Safari browser on an iphone, and according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow), `clip` is unfortunately not supported in Safari, hence the discrepancy you are seeing.

I tried messing around to see if I could achieve the effect you're looking for. One possible solution is to introduce one more wrapping div around the `img`.

```
const HeroBackground = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ImageWrapper>
        <Background src="/images/backgrounds/hero-background.svg" />
      </ImageWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default HeroBackground

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: auto;
  /* overflow-x: clip !important; ***cannot use!*** */
`

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
`

const Background = styled.img`
  /* position: absolute; ***remove*** */
  /* z-index: -1; ***remove*** */
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
  }
`
```

There are three keys to this working:

- The additional wrapper div allows you to position the image statically so that it contributes to height. The div is therefore what becomes absolutely positioned.
- `max-width: 100vw` means the div will never be longer than the screen.
- And `overflow: hidden` means the image won't leak out of its constraining div.

  - Using `hidden` on `Wrapper` hides the entire image because it ends up with 0 height. This is why the extra div is introduced.

I also recommend investigating if there's a way to use your image as a `background-image`.

Comment: Yes, the solution works! 
It was weird because i tested it on many devices including android phone but overflow-x clip seems not working too.
Thanks for the solution ,although i still a little bit confused about the extra div.

Comment: Still works perfectly. @BagusAmrullahFikri The extra div is so that overflow:clip can be turned off of the parent (the div that has the images currently sat in. and then the absolutely positioned div lets you move the content outside the parent. Overflow still works, but can now be hidden on the direct image wrapper, whilst allowing visible overflow on the parent)

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue on IOS / Safari but I just noticed that [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow) now shows that `overflow: clip` will be supported on Safari in IOS 16.0:)

That's something to consider from this point onwards before implementing workarounds to get this to work on IOS. It then all comes down to how many of your users are on older IOS versions in the future and how big the impact is of `overflow: clip` not working. In my case the impact is limited to some content highlighting sticking out further than intended on the older IOS versions, which is something I can live with.

Comment: Is using `overflow-x: hidden` instead of `overflow-x: clip` an option for you? This is how I solved the issue for myself. I needed `overflow-x: clip` on larger screens, but for mobile devices `overflow: hidden` is sufficient so just shoved that in a media query.

Comment: That might actually also work in some cases indeed! In my case there was a reason for not using "hidden" although it might also have solved the issue when using hidden only on mobile and clip on larger screens as you suggest. In my case though there are areas in the site where I need specifically clip even on mobile as I use it in combination with `overflow-clip-margin` , which is also a very useful property.

Answer (score 1):

I use this CSS class for `overflow-x: clip`:

```css
.polyfill-overflow-x-clip {
  /* On Safari mobile browsers, overflow-x-clip is not supported */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-x: clip;
}
```